# R Likert and Grouped unused levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, likert

I'm using the R Likert package to generate graphs, which I've used for years but have never come across this bug.

My Likert summary looks fine (generated using `likert::likert(dat, grouping = dat$group)` :

| Group | Item | Strongly Disagree | Disagree | Slightly Disagree | Slightly Agree | Agree | Strongly Agree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | Item 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 80 |
| Group 1 | Item 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 80 |
| Group 2 | Item 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 10 | 40 | 50 |
| Group 2 | Item 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 20 | 60 | 20 |

However, this will not plot:
`plot(likert::likert(dat, grouping = dat$group)`

`Error in seq_len(n) : argument must be coercible to non-negative integer`

I'm pretty sure it relates to the grouping/and or the skew in the data, as I can generate a plot for each Group individually no worries, or if I artificially create a new row in my dataset and add a single Strongly Disagree to each item and group, then it works fine, producing the grouped plot with both items?!?!

This only occurs for the bar type, it doesn't happen if I set the density plot option `plot(q_ab.s, type = "density")`

I've also noticed that if I produce any plot with `likert()` that has an unused level (common with the small samples I work with), the formatting is totally weird, with a big empty box at the top. I wonder if this is related?

[image]

So confused. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Did you try using the nlevels argument. Help text says,  
"number of possible levels. Only necessary if there are missing levels."

Comment: Thanks stomper - I did, no effect unfortunately

Comment: It's imperfect, but I kind of got it working. I dropped the missing levels on the factors first. This means I only have 3 categories instead of six, so only the Agree to S. Agree. Plotted. Not ideal by any means.